# I am trying to make a guild add message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make it so when my bot is added to another server, it will send an embed saying how many servers it's in now and the guild name and also the guild owner. I am also trying to make another embed so it tells me when it leaves a server and tells me when it joined the server first and then when it was removed and the guild name and guild owner. I use discord.js. Could someone help, please? This is my current script:

```js
bot.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    const joinserverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Joined a server!")
        .addField("Guild name:", `${guild.name}`)
        .addField("Time of join:", `${Discord.Guild.createdTimestamp()}`)
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setThumbnail(guild.displayAvatarURL())
    if (guilds.channel.id = 740121026683207760) {
        channel.send(joinserverembed)
    }
    guild.channel.send("Thank you for inviting Ultra Bot Premium! Please use up!introduction and up!help for the new perks and more!")
})

bot.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    const leftserverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Left a server!")
        .addField("Guild name:", `${guild.name}`)
        .addField("Time of removal:", `${createdTimestamp()}`)
        .setColor("RED")
        .setThumbnail(guild.displayAvatarURL())
    if (guilds.channel.id = 740121026683207760) {
        channel.send(leftserverembed)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved your first issue for you in the code below.

- You were doing `guild.channel.send()`, in this case, `guild` represents a `Discord.Guild` however you're using it like it represents an instance of `Message`, which it does not.

You can use `guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name == 'general').send("Thanks for inviting me to this server¬!")` will send a message to a channel named `general` in that server.

```js
bot.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
  const joinserverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Joined a server!")
    .addField("Guild name:", guild.name)
    .addField("Time of join:", Date.now())
    .setColor("GREEN")
    .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }));
  bot.channels.cache.get("740121026683207760").send(joinserverembed);
  guild.channels.cache
    .filter((c) => c.type === "text")
    .random()
    .send(
      "Thank you for inviting Ultra Bot Premium! Please use up!introduction and up!help for the new perks and more!"
    );
});
```

I filter the channels in the guild, ensuring that they are not categories or voice channels, then send the welcome message to a random one.

As for your second query, you need to use a database, store the Date.now timestamp of when it was added, then once the bot has left the guild it must get the value and display its time. I haven't done this for you, but I have fixed your code:

```js
bot.on("guildDelete", (guild) => {
  const leftserverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Left a server!")
    .addField("Guild name:", guild.name)
    .addField("Time of removal:", Date.now())
    .setColor("RED")
    .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }));
  bot.channels.cache.get("740121026683207760").send(leftserverembed);
});
```